# Combining ‘replies’ and ‘responses’

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I am trying to construct a sentence that covers both replies and responses.

> No need for you to answer this question. I went over your (replies/responses) in this conversation and know that your answer is yes.

Can you combine both meanings like this?

> No need for you to answer this question. I **went over everything you said** in this conversation and know that your answer is yes.

Is ‘reply’ or ‘responses’ using “I went over everything you said in this conversation” better as it covers replies and responses?

I want to mention that their general replies as well as responses to questions from the conversation we had is how I came to the conclusion that the answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need the word “**had**” or is the sentence fine without it? //// Also, should the end of the sentence be “**I know the answer**” or just ”**know the know answer**”

Comment: You don't need "had", because there's nothing in what you said that would require past perfect. You could leave out the "I" or include it; the sentence works either way.